# MongoDB How to make 2 nested documents have the same _id?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I currently have 2 documents in my mongodb collection. They are:

```
"_id": "5b6c7109c21dfe2a4b557b1e",
"title": "Childish Gambino",
"datetime": "2018-09-16T00:00:00.000Z",
"venue": {
     "name": "Madison Square Garden",
     "city": "New York",
     "state": "NY"
     "_id": "5b6c7109c21dfe2a4b557b1d",
}
```

and

```
"_id": "5b6c71133acdbe2a4e51615d",
"title": "The Eagles",
"datetime": "2018-09-12T00:00:00.000Z",
"venue": {
     "name": "Madison Square Garden",
     "city": "New York",
     "state": "NY"
     "_id": "5b6c71133acdbe2a4e51615c",
}
```

Although these are two different concerts, both take place at Madison Square Garden. However, in the 2 documents, Madison Square Garden has 2 different "_id" attributes. Is there a way I can make them have the same _id or would I have to manually input the same _id every time I add a document that takes place at Madison Square Garden? Is manually inputting _id generally considered an okay practice? New to mongodb so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use MongoDB version 3.4 and up you could use `$lookup` which means that in your schema you could add a `reference` to the actual `Madison Square Garden` (which I assume resides in another collection). This way your data could look something like this:

```
"_id": ObjectId('5b6c71133acdbe2a4e51615d'),
"title": "The Eagles",
"datetime": "2018-09-12T00:00:00.000Z",
"venueId": ObjectId('5b6c71133acdbe2a4e51615c')
```

And you would be able to cross-reference that venue using the [$lookup feature](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

**Note**: This is by no means more efficient than having the data embedded but it gives you one reference _id.

Comment: While $lookup is possible, it's not as efficient as nesting the data and reading from a single collection. In this example, the name and city fields of the venue will never change, so it's a good candidate for embedding.

Comment: Oh no doubt, I agree with you ... but the OP question was about having same IDs so ...